# WiFi keeps trying to reconnect all by itself. The tray icon animation is almost runnying nonstop

Tags: 14.04, thinkpad, system-tray, iwlwifi

The WiFi on my ubuntu 14.04 installation is very unreliable.

- wireless re-connections out of the blue
- sometimes it takes up to 15 min until a connection is established

Hardware hardware is a `Centrino Wireless-N 2200`.

I have turned the power management function for the wireless card off without seeing any improvements. My computer is 30 cm next to my router. Another computer running Debian Wheezy has no problems with this WiFi. :(

**What else can I do?**

[image]